# How can I unfold the recurrence: T(n)=2T((n+2)/3) + 1

Tags: algorithms, recursion

I'm trying to solve this recurrence, but I don't know how to unfold it:
I am looking for a function $T:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies
$$
    T(n)=2 \cdot T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{3}\right\rfloor\right) + 1
$$
for all $n\ge4$. The initial values are $T(1)=T(2)=T(3)=1$.

---

> Question: 
>   Can I ignore that "$+2$" and solve it as it was $2T(n/3) + 1$?

Note: This comes from a from a problem that uses a `V[a..b]` 
array and makes this return:

```
return V(X) + f(V, a, Y) + f(V, Z, b)
```

Where $Y$ is $(2a+b)/3$ and $Z$ is $(a+2b)/3$.
Hence: $((b-a+3)/3) = ((n+2)/3)$.

Comment: Is your recurrence equation complete? Plugging in $n=1$ gives $T(1) = -1$.

Comment: When n<=3  f(n) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=3^m+1$ then

$$T(n)=T(3^m+1) = 2T(3^{m-1}+1)+1=2^mT(3^0+1)+2^m-1 \\=(n-1)^{\log_3(2)} (T(2)+1)-1$$

and since $\log_3(2)\approx 0.63$ this will be $o(n)$.

With the initial values and rounding, the recurrence is monotonic increasing and so is $o(n)$ in general

Answer (score 0):

The substitution $T(n)=2^{f(n)}-1$ shifts the given recurrence into
$$f(n)= f\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{3}\right\rfloor\right) + 1$$
for $n\ge4$, with initial values $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1$.

Now you can prove with induction that $f(n)=k$ for all integers $n$ from the range $3^{k-1}<n\le3^k$ with $k\ge2$.

Hence, $f(n)$ grows asymptotically like $\log_3(n)$ and $T(n)$ grows asymptotically like $n^{\log_3(2)}$.